# What does the word 「ものかねえ」mean?

Tags: words, manga

The word comes from the below sentence which is said by a frightened boxer who was going to box with his very strong opponent.

> なんとか打たれずしてすんなり負ける方法はない**ものかねえ**!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/use-of-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b-with-%e3%82%82%e3%81%86%e3%81%99%e3%81%93%e3%81%97-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「なんとか打{う}たれずしてすんなり負{ま}ける方法{ほうほう}は**ないものかねえ**！」

The pattern:

> 「[Noun] + は + ないもの + かね/かな/だろうか, etc.」

is an informal expression meaning:

> "I wonder if there really is no [Noun]"

The noun phrase here is 「なんとか打たれずしてすんなり負ける方法」, meaning "way to lose easily without getting punched somehow".