# what is the もの in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

もっと楽な道ってないもんかしら？

How would the meaning change if i removed the もの?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6477/9831

Comment: So its like "i wonder..."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of 〜ないものか　with もうすこし／どうにか／なんとか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/use-of-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b-with-%e3%82%82%e3%81%86%e3%81%99%e3%81%93%e3%81%97-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8b)

Answer (score 1):

もの is a sentence final particle here. It adds a slight sense of dissatisfaction.

[Etymology of もん・もの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/etymology-of-%e3%82%82%e3%82%93-%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae)